# How to add Brushes in 2.8

Tags: sculpting, customization, installation

Trying to add brushes to blender.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0CwLvcmXQQ) but nothing is the same anymore, I am using 2.80 latest build.

Trying to add [these brushes](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/86419), but I cannot find anything on how to add in 2.80. Thought I had it once but they disappeared once I click on one.

Comment: Asking for tutorials, links or resources is considered off topic here. Could you please rephrase your question so if focuses more on solving the problem and less on google searching?

Answer (score 7):

1. Click Append in File menu
2. Browse file \ Brush and select brushes you need (b for box select)
3. In Sculpt mode click on brush preview image and select one

[image: Brushes append]

Updated:

Brushes will be saved in you curent file.

> Thought I had it once but they disappeared once I click on one.

That mean you have not saved your brushes in Startup file. If you need these brushes in each your project - you need to save they in Startup.

[image: Save as Startup]

Be careful - with brushes **all other data** (objects, UI and so on..) will be saved as Startup! Preferably create New file, import brushes and then save Startup file.

[Blend file with brushes](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51827)

Comment: tried to open the saved file and found just **one** brush. 

seems like, blender won't set brush textures by user and they become purged by saving. 

I think this is a small beta bug, needed to be reported

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help. will give it a try.

Comment: Why doesn't the brush in .psd file format show up when I try to append it?

Comment: M'I doing something wrong ? I'm using Blender 2.82, I follow exactly all these steps, and everytime I start a project, I have to import my brushes, not to mention that all the thumbnails are not being shown when I enter the sculpt mode.